# SQL datetime less than NOW() returns invalid results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run the following SQL statement

```
SELECT
  P.team_id,
  P.id,
  M.id,
  P.`end`,
  UHT.user_id
FROM phase P 
INNER JOIN module M
  ON P.Module_id = M.id
JOIN user_has_team UHT
  ON UHT.team_id = P.team_id
WHERE
  M.module_type = 7 OR
  M.module_type = 8 AND
  P.end < NOW();
```

This result returns 180 rows. if i go to the bottom of these rows i get a result that looks like this:

```
'52', '130', '275', '2014-12-16 00:00:00', '49'
```

This is just 1 out of many.

First i thought "Hey maybe the server time is invalid"

But when i run `SELECT NOW()` i get the following result:

```
'2014-11-02 19:38:49'
```

So what could the problem be?

Comment: Please stop tagging your MySql questions as SQL Server. There is no `now()` function there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some more parenthesis because of operator precedence in SQL.

Try changing your WHERE clause from

```
WHERE M.module_type = 7 or M.module_type = 8 AND P.end < NOW();
```

to

```
WHERE (M.module_type = 7 or M.module_type = 8) AND P.end < NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into operator precedence,your query is interpreted as:

```
WHERE (M.module_type = 7) 
or 
((M.module_type = 8) 
AND P.end < NOW());
```

But you need

```
WHERE (M.module_type = 7 or M.module_type = 8) AND P.end < NOW();
```